# Android - Spinner not correctly aligning to end of parent

Tags: android, android-spinner

For my App I need to have a spinner aligned to the right end of its parent.

this is my spinner xml:

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/createsub_cycle_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
```

see, `alignParentEnd` is set to `true`.

Still when I run the app the resut is the following:

[image: gap]

the gap on the right of "weekly" shouldn't be there. it should be aligned to the very end of the blue layout.

How do I fix it?

EDIT:

Here is the Whole layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/createsub_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/createsub_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="20dp" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/createsub_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/createsub_user_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:onClick="onTitleClicked"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:layout_below="@id/createsub_title"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/createsub_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/createsub_title"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/createsub_currency_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
            android:dropDownWidth="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/createsub_user_title"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/createsub_user_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/createsub_currency_spinner"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/createsub_currency_spinner"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:hint="0.00"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:layout_below="@id/createsub_price"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/createsub_cycle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/createsub_price"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/cycle"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/createsub_cycle_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:layout_below="@id/createsub_cycle"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/createsub_firstbill"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/createsub_cycle"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/first_bill"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


        <!--TODO: when clicked has to show datepickerdialog-->
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/createsub_user_firstbill"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:layout_below="@id/createsub_firstbill"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/createsub_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/createsub_firstbill"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/duration"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/createsub_duration_selector"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:layout_below="@id/createsub_duration"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/createsub_remindme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/createsub_duration"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/remind_me"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/createsub_reminder_selector"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/createsub_user_firstbill"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two things you can try:

1. I notice that you are hardcoding the `android:dropDownWidth` to `40dp`. The text "weekly" may not necessarily span `40dp` in length. Try removing that attribute.
2. Try setting the spinner's background to null to remove the space for the caret

   ```
   <Spinner
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@null"/>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was partially it. The other thing was that the spinner is based on an array and in that array there are strings that are longer than "weekly", so he was keeping the space for them. I solved it by adding `android:textAlignment="viewEnd"` in my `spinner_item.xml` aligning the text to the end and thus removing the gap.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

`android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"`

In the cardview tag remove this

`android:layout_margin="10dp"`;

Comment: thanks for the answer. after removing it, it moves 10dp to the riight but not to the very end of the layout

Comment: Post the entire layout ,

Comment: Please, have a look at the updated question. I have added the whole layout. It is quite long

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: removing the CardView margin removes the outer margin, which I need, and does not fix the problem